# Spring Boot JAR file not working with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a Spring Boot Application that is working.

I did

```
mvn clean package
```

and the *.jar* file is my *target* folder.

Then I try to execute the following command:

```
java -jar .\target\my-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and I get the following Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\Users\test\example-application\example-app/src/main/test/ExampleApplication
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
```

Researching on stackoverflow just recommend an issue that I already included ...
It was recommended to include this plugin in order to include the maven jars into the project .... *spring-boot-maven-plugin*

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
```

What else could be the reason for it not working?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the jar? Run `jar -tf target\my-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` to list the files it contains to start with...

Comment: Yes, its under ..BOOT-INF/classes/test/ExampleApplication.class . Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class name in the exception is a file name and not a class name. That makes me suspect that you have specified the main class incorrectly. Have you specified the name of the class in the spring-boot-maven-plugin with

```
<configuration>
  <mainClass>foo.bar.ExampleApplication</mainClass>
</configuration>
```

or as a Main-Class in the manifest? Note that you should use dot notation for packages...

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue to this a few weeks ago. Spring looks for the source for most classes to be in the `/src/main` folder.
It looks like you're missing the file from that folder. In my case, I had placed it in just `/src` instead of `/src/main`

Comment: Also correct thank you very much. However I can specify the main class as config to the maven library mentioned in my description as @Per Huss answered.